# MPVolumeView equivalent for Android

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth, mpvolumeview

Does anyone know if there is an equivalent to [MPVolumeView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPVolumeView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) available in Android?

Basically, it's a a built in component in iOS that can present users with a system volume slider, and / or (what I'm really after in Android) a list of available bluetooth / Airplay audio output options (i.e. bluetooth speakers). The image below shows it in action:

[image: MPVolumeView listing available audio output routes]

Is there any easy option for listing bluetooth etc. audio routing options in Android, or do you have to write all the scanning, connecting, audio routing code yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the lack of response, and the endless googling around the subject of connecting to A2DP Bluetooth sinks, that I've been doing lately, the sad answer to this question seems to be no, there is nothing quite like the MPVolumeView in Android.

The nearest thing would be to either write it all yourself, as I feared, or, to simply pop open the system Bluetooth options windows from your app (ensuring you've got `BLUETOOTH_ADMIN` permissions set up in your manifest first):

```
Intent intentOpenBluetoothSettings = new Intent();
intentOpenBluetoothSettings.setAction(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_BLUETOOTH_SETTINGS); 
startActivity(intentOpenBluetoothSettings);
```